What is the best test to run to compare presence/absence of something between sampling locations?
I have data on the presence/absence of four different pathogens found in edible crabs in 7 locations over 2 seasons. For this study, 30 crabs were collected from each site and for each crab the presence or absence of each pathogen was recorded. I want to know if the total frequency of each pathogen differs between the 7 sites but I am unsure how to analyse this.
What test or model must I run on this data to achieve this? Can I perform a binomial ANOVA or can I use a Chi-Square test? The data look a bit like this except there are 60 samples from each site instead of 5 (0 = absent, 1 = present):

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Interesting question, but it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. I will flag this question for migration.
